Invalid block tag on line 1: 'include'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
During a Django tutorial I've got an issue with the index.html file. I can't handle this exception:

Invalid block tag on line 3: 'include'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

I really don't understand why it doesn't recognize "include".
My index.html is like this:
<h1>{{ title }}</h1>

{% include 'alphas/includes/nav.html' %}

<ul>
    {% for item in posts %}
    {% if item.is_published %}
    <li>
        <h2>{{ item.title }}</h2>
        <p>{{ item.content }}</p>
        <p><a href="{% url 'post' item.id %}">Читать пост</a></p>
        {% if not forloop.last%}
        <hr>
        {% endif %}
    </li>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>


I think it's the django version, I downgraded from the 5 version to the 4.2 and the error disappeared

In 5.0, include is still a default template tag: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/templates/builtins/#include Since this is also in the tests of the Django project, I don't think that is the issue.
